# Blind deconvolution of a function convolved with itself

Tags: functional-analysis, inverse, signal-processing

I have a function/vector $f$ that I know is the result of an unknown function $g$ convolved with itself:

$f = g \ast g$

Is there any way to do a blind deconvolution on $f$ with this constraint?

Comment: You need to know one of the inputs to the convolution, otherwise there are uncountably many input pairs that will give the same output. You can see this by looking at the frequency domain representation of the problem: $f = g \ast h \leftrightarrow F = G \cdot H$. If you know both $F$ and $G$, then $H$ is simply $F/G$ ($G \neq 0$). However, knowing only $F$ is not enough since $\forall G\in\mathbb{C}$ there exists some $H$ such that $F=G \cdot H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the Fourier transform, we have
$$
\widehat{f} = \widehat{g}^2,
$$
so that $\widehat{g} = \sqrt{\widehat{f}}$.  Then take the inverse Fourier transform to find $g$.  This doesn't quite work, I think, because you have to choose a branch of the square root.  I think this shows the solution is not unique, but you can still find them by this method.